# RecyclerView Adapter - NotifyItemRemoved - Removed item appears again after scroll

Tags: android, xamarin, android-recyclerview, xamarin.android

I think I am doing it all wrong, but I have a RecyclerView Adapter and simple button click (in this case a `LinearLayout`) which triggers the following

```
this.NotifyItemRemoved(position);
```

The full button code is the following

```
public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
..........
        LinearLayout _ARC = V.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.moreArc);
        _ARC.Click += async delegate {
        try
        {
          Log.Info("101029", "ARC_Clicked");
          await usersAct.SWITCH_ARCHIVE(ID); // some user action
          this.NotifyItemRemoved(position);                   
        }
        catch (Exception X)
        {
          Log.Info("101029", "ERROR AT ARC_Clicked: " + X.Message);
        }
        };
.......
}
```

This works fine and the item gets removed nicely, but when I scroll down in the `recyclerview` and go back up to the position from where the item was removed, the item appears back.

I think I am doing it all wrong or my logic is not correct? Any idea?

Comment: `NotifyItemRemoved` only removes it from the display (if displaying) and causes the moving (animation) of the other on screen elements, you will also need to the actually remove the backing data from however your adapter is storing it.

Comment: Oh, that's what I initially thought, but I don't think I can do that from `public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder`?  Or will I have to do this in my fragment where i am setting the `adapter`  as `RecyclerView.SetAdapter(adapter);`?

Comment: @SushiHangover you are a genius :) thank you, yeah i found the way to remove it as per your comments - Can you please write this as an answer and I will mark it as an accepted answer: I removed the item from the actual `List` using `.RemoveAt(index)` function as it was a `List`

Comment: I added an answer that shows how you can use an `ObservableCollection` to do all the `Notify***` work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NotifyItemRemoved` *only* removes it from the display (if displaying or in its view cache) and causes the moving (animation) of the other on-screen elements/views, you will also need to the actually remove the backing data from your adapter however you are storing it.

As an example, I have a `RecyclerView.Adapter` subclass that stores its data as an `ObservableCollection<SomeClass>` in an instance variable called `myDataCollection` within the adapter.

In the initialization of the adapter (the `.ator` for me), I register a `CollectionChanged` event on the `ObservableCollection` that I pass into the constructor, i.e.:

```
myDataCollection.CollectionChanged += CollectionChanged;
```

That event within my adapter subclass is defined as:

```
void CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Action)
    {
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
            NotifyItemRangeInserted(e.NewStartingIndex, e.NewItems.Count);
            break;
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
            NotifyItemRangeRemoved(e.OldStartingIndex, e.OldItems.Count);
            break;
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move:
            NotifyItemMoved(e.OldStartingIndex, e.NewStartingIndex);
            break;
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
            NotifyAll();
            break;
    }
}
```

Now anytime I make a change to the `ObservableCollection`, the adapter is notified of the change and updates the `RecyclerView` that is it observing.

So now you can make you changes adds/deletes/moves to **just** the `ObservableCollection` and the `RecyclerView` is "auto-magically" updated.

This also works if you end up using `Filter` within your adapter to implement a search feature in your `RecyclerView`.

Note: This does not update the inflated views within the RecyclerView if properties of the objects within the `ObservableCollection` change, but that can be done via `PropertyChangedEventHandler` on your objects if needed...

Comment: Wow, this is just perfect solution :) thank you for that

Comment: @aliusman no problem, it works really well, also for `Filter` work, so as your search adds/removes/moves items in the ObservableCollection, the recyclerview updates with all the correct animations ;-) Also if you use drag/drop in the recyclerview via a ItemTouchHelper.

Comment: Yes, this is just perfect :) I am not using 'itemTouchHelper' but after this thinking about using it. FYI I am trying to find the right emoji for my excitement lol

Comment: My only change was to replace NotifyAll with NotifyDataSetChanged