# notifyDataSetChanged doesn't work when i am reading from sqlite

Tags: java, android, xamarin

When I attempt to read from SQLite and use adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged. I don't see any changes in my recyclerView.
The main idea is to search in SQLite where the name contains a value from a textView. 
Then to repopulate again my adapter.

I create an Instance

```
 private List<InventoryPreviewClass> mItems;
 private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
 adpInventoryPreview adapter;
```

Then inside onCreate() method

```
mItems = db.Query<InventoryPreviewClass>("select * from InventoryPreviewClass where CategoryID =" + CategoryID + ""); //Here i am reading from sqlite

mRecyclerView.HasFixedSize = true;
var layout = new GridLayoutManager(this, InventoryRowsPerLine, GridLayoutManager.Vertical, false);
mRecyclerView.SetLayoutManager(layout);
adapter = new adpInventoryPreview(mItems);
mRecyclerView.SetAdapter(adapter);
```

Until now the code works. 
My recyclerView is populated with my items from sqlite.

Here is the method when a user types something in TextView

```
private void EtSearchAlwaysOn_TextChanged(object sender, Android.Text.TextChangedEventArgs e)
{      
   mItems = db.Query<InventoryPreviewClass>("select * from InventoryPreviewClass where  InventoryItemName like '%" + etSearchAlwaysOn.Text.ToUpper() + "%'");
   adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

When I am typing something nothing changes in my recyclerView.
Why is this happening?

The only way I found that this works is to reset my items inside my adapter for example:

```
mItems = db.Query<InventoryPreviewClass>("select * from InventoryPreviewClass where  InventoryItemName like '%" + etSearchAlwaysOn.Text.ToUpper() + "%'");
adapter = new adpInventoryPreview(mItems);
mRecyclerView.SetAdapter(adapter);
```

Why is this happening? I don't think that the second method is right.

Comment: 1st: pass your `mItems` by `ref` 2nd: Instead of trying to reset the entire adapter, implement a `Filter` subclass (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filter) and use it within your `RecyclerView.Adapter` to allow a filtered set of `mitems` to dynamically update your  `RecyclerView` to prevent the UI from "flashing" (a constant clearing of the entire view upon each user keypress that updates the sql query). 3rd: Review my answer here on how to do selective notifications: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50692948/4984832

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a byRef issue.
You pass memory pointer 1 to your adapter and tell it to monitor for changes.

Then you load a list and repoint your memory pointer to spot 2.
Then you tell adapter that it's monitored memory at pointer 1 has changed.

You have two options.

- Modify the original list by comparing new results with old results, removing and adding as necessary
- or Tell the adapter it has a new memory pointer that it is monitoring by changing the items inside the adapter. Making a method for swapItems(items) will work. Then call notifyDataSetChanged inside the adapter.

Comment: Thank you Sam. I prefer method 2. It seems more flexible for me. Do i need to dispose adapter before this? To inform some how that the previous point in memory doesnt exist any more? For avoiding memory leaks?

Comment: good question. I never worry about the old list as when you repoint it to a new location, the garbage collection should do it's job.

Comment: @Sam I think he is talking about the disposal of the adapter. Dmo you should not dispose of, the adapter at all in this case because then you will lose on the viewholder cache that your adapter creates.

Comment: oh sorry, didn't catch that. No you don't need to dispose of the adapter. Thanks droidchef. I thought you were asking about the old list.

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because you are assigning a new object to `mItems`

The first time you create the `mItems` list, you pass it onto your adapter, when the next time you are getting a response from your SQLite DB is creating a new instance of the list since you are assigning it to the object.

What you need to do is

- Create a method in the adapter that accepts your items like `adapter.updateItems(newItems)`
- The method should clear the list like `items.clear()` and then add the new items you passed it with `items.addAll(newItems)`
- After that you can call `notifyDataSetChanged()` within the adapter itself and it will work.

In your, adapter it will look like this

```
public void updateItems(final List<InventoryPreviewClass> newItems) {
   items.clear();
   items.addAll(newItems);
   notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

and then you can call it like this

```
updatedList = db.Query<InventoryPreviewClass>("select * from InventoryPreviewClass where CategoryID =" + CategoryID + "");

adapter.updateItems(updatedList);
```

I think you missed the point that this is the typical case of pass by value and not pass by reference.

Comment: Yes, it seems the best approach. Thanks @droidchef

Answer (score 1):

you have to set items in your adapter,
create a setter like this :

> ```
> private List<InventoryPreviewClass> mItems;
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   public void setItems(List<InventoryPreviewClass> items)
>    {
>     mItems=items;
>    }
> ```

and then update your search method like this

```
private void EtSearchAlwaysOn_TextChanged(object sender, 
 Android.Text.TextChangedEventArgs e)
 {      
 mItems = db.Query<InventoryPreviewClass>("select * from InventoryPreviewClass 
 where  InventoryItemName like '%" + etSearchAlwaysOn.Text.ToUpper() + "%'");
 adapter.setItems(mItems);
 adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Notify adapter after you set adapter.

```
mItems = db.Query<InventoryPreviewClass>("select * from InventoryPreviewClass where InventoryItemName like '%" + etSearchAlwaysOn.Text.ToUpper() + "%'");

adapter = new adpInventoryPreview(mItems);

mRecyclerView.SetAdapter(adapter);

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Your answer works! Do i need to dispose my adapter before creating a new one for avoiding memory leaks?

Comment: This is an incorrect way of doing it because you will destroy the adapter every single time.
You will lose the complete purpose of having a view cache of your view holder in the recyclerview if you destroy adapter every single time.

Comment: What is best approach to achieve this @droidchef

Comment: Check my answer, I mentioned the approach. The idea is not create an adapter over and over again.

It will have a performance impact because your adapter will have to recreate the views for your recycler view.